# stop repetition of data displayed, foreach loop php, mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach, repeat

I have a code which gives me list of addresses in my view file but some addresses are repeated. I don't want to display the ones which are already displayed.

```
$address_array[] = '-- Select address --';

foreach($address as $addres){
    $address_array[$addres->id] = $addres->town;
}
```

Any idea on stopping the repetition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `in_array` function, you can check if a value already exists in your array

```
$address_array[] = '-- Select address --';

foreach($address as $addres){
    if (!in_array($addres->town, $address_array)) $address_array[$addres->id] = $addres->town;
}
```

Comment: I get answer in 3 mins but stackoverflow won't allow me to accept. That script did the magic. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I'll be slower next time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use array_unique to erase duplicates.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

A little example :

```
$address = array_unique($address);
```